# Enable GPCLK line for 1MHz (or greater) clock

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio, spi

I'm trying to drive a [TLC5940](http://www.ti.com/product/tlc5940) with a brand new RPi Model A+ (V1). I plan to use the Pi's SPI bus to pipe data to the chip, which I've done successfully before using an AVR. The part I'm stuck with is generating a regular greyscale clock for the chip at about 1MHz (the actual frequency doesn't really matter, but it's definitely in the megahertz range).

How can I get GPCLK0 (pin 7/GPIO 7) to output a 1MHz+ clock signal using rpi.gpio in Python? Ideally I'd like to be able to control the frequency.

I found [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5506/ad7705-analog-to-digital-converter-with-rpi-viable) about using GPLK0 as a clock for an ADC, however the answer is just "use a crystal" which I don't want to do. Additionally, [this question about turning a GPIO to it's alternative output mode](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3469/how-can-i-turn-an-gpio-to-its-alternate-function) didn't help either. I did find [an article that uses the one wire bus](http://idledeveloper.com/tag/gpclk0/), and [a forum post on how to set up the pin as a clock source in C](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=11127) but nothing in Python.

Answer (score 3):

RPi.GPIO (as far as I am aware) has no support for setting the clocks.

You could access the raw clock device from Python using code similar to that shown at http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=641670#p641670

I have an example standalone C program which sets the clock frequency "Minimal clock access" at http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Misc_code.  This shows the sort of functionality you'll need to port to Python.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm going to try using the PWM pins with rpi.gpio and see where that gets me

Comment: @Bojangles As far as I am aware RPi.GPIO only has software timed PWM support, perhaps a few kHz.